# Use of unicode characters in Haddock documentation

Tags: haskell, unicode, haddock

Haddock seems to incorrectly re-encode non-ASCII characters in the documentation in UTF-8 encoded source files. I often need to include mathematical formulas in the documentation and they are much more readable if some common math symbols such as summation (∑) can be used.

However, after running the files through haddock, these symbols become blank squares. 
Haddock has the option `--use-unicode` but that just converts function arrows in function signatures etc. into unicode characters, while still breaking the actually documentation.

Even better would be if this can be controlled from `cabal haddock`!

I'm using Haddock version 2.9.4.

Comment: You can use `&#962;` and such for non-ASCII symbols.

Comment: OK, but then the source becomes unreadable...

Comment: True, but if haddock doesn't automatically handle UTF-8, not knowing its innards, that's the best I can offer at the moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that Haddock uses the GHC API to do parsing.  Non-ASCII characters in comments are not handled properly by GHC < 7.4, but it seems that with GHC 7.4 it works fine.

Comment: It all has been patched up since this answer and Haddock now does unicode in comments just fine.

Answer (score 4):

If UTF-8 cannot be used and numeric character references like `&#8721;` or `&­#x2211;` (these are correct references for the n-ary summation symbol ∑) are regarded as unreadable, then I’m afraid the only option is to use named references like `&sum;`, if they get passed thru to the HTML result **and** are supported by the browser(s) that will be used.

That’s a big “if,” since the new HTML5 entities have rather limited support, but perhaps in an intranet where everyone uses Firefox... HTML5 entities:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/named-character-references.html

(And most of the references are not as mnemonic as `&sum;`.)